# i have inserted a video tag in my html code,on page loading iam unable to view the video

Tags: html

/* the video file is not get loaded,in the area on webpage it shows "no video with supported format and MIME type found */

The video exists in mp 4 format.need to place it in the webpage

Comment: What browser are you testing on? And how does your HTML look?

Comment: <table bgcolor="#015754" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="628">
         <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="top">
          <!-- here goes img--><a href=""><!--img src="images/banner-2.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 0; padding:0;"--></a>
          <video width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source src="images/aloha.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>

          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>

Comment: the code is posted can any one guide me,i tried it to do both on FF and chome browser.not working.i need the look of you tube video on a web page

Answer (score -1):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      </video>
```

Your browser does not support the video tag.

Comment: SHOULD I CHANGE TO THIS AND SEE

Answer (score -1):

If you're a Firefox user, update to the latest version. It is an error that comes only once. Just `ctrl`+`Shift`+`R` once and check.
The bug was [fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=990623) yesterday (03/03/2015) by Mozilla

-- update --

Dude, I just tested your code. The video source is not properly linked (not found)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MercS.jpg]

You can always press `ctrl`+`Shift`+`K` on Firefox to see the resource loading events upon page load. Right clicking and `Q` (Inspect Element) on a video and check the URL validity yourself.

Comment: I TRIED ITS NOT WORKING

Comment: make sure the link to mp4 is correct too. can you post the html code of the video

Comment: <table bgcolor="#015754" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="628">
         <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="top">
          <!-- here goes img--><a href=""><!--img src="images/banner-2.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 0; padding:0;"--></a>
          <video width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source src="images/aloha.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>

          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>

Comment: add any short video of your choice

Comment: i just tried ammending my code and its the same,the display of my video on firefox browser and on chromium browser are different

Comment: Your coding is correct. Linking of the video source is incorrect

Comment: thanks for your support,i resolved the issue by changing the path of video file

Comment: You're Welcome, then mark my answer as final and close this question